# On products of involutions

Tags: linear-algebra, involutions

Is it possible to write $$M = \begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&-\dfrac{1}{x}\end{bmatrix}, x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$$
 into a product of two involutory real matrices? I know that it can be written as a product of three but is it possible to reduce it to two?

Answer (score 3):

$M$ can be written as product of two involutions if and only if $x=\pm 1$.

To see this, let us first observe the following : If $M=M_1M_2$ such that $M_i^2=1$ for $i=1,2$, then $M_1MM_1^{-1}=M_1^2M_2M_1^{-1}=M_2^{-1}M_1^{-1}=M^{-1}$. So if possible let there exist such a matrix $M_1=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}$. Then $M_1M=M^{-1}M_1$ implies $b=c=0$ and $a(x^2-1)=d(x^2-1)=0$. Therefore if $x\neq \pm 1$, then $a=d=0$.

Comment: It's a nice proof, I just want to clarify how the 'observation' becomes a proof: firstly it is easy to see if $x= \pm 1$ then $M$ can be written as a product of two involutions. Then for the converse suppose $M$ is a product of two involutions, and suppose to the contrary that $x \neq \pm 1$ - then the observation becomes a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Further remarks: in general, from this paper: http://www.culturagalega.org/album/docs/textos_214_18.pdf
a matrix is a product of two involutions if and only if it is invertible and similar to its inverse. With this you can shorten the proof to the last two lines...+1 from me btw

Comment: Good job! A similar way of using that idea: You showed that $M$ and $M^{-1}$ should be conjugate to each other in the affirmative case. Therefore their respective sets of eigenvalues, $\{x,-1/x\}$ and $\{1/x,-x\}$ should coincide. This happens iff $x=\pm1$.